# Converting game's x,y coordinates to Google Earth lat/long

Tags: math, geolocation, gis, geospatial

I'm trying to convert coordinates from a game's  Earth map to values in a Google Earth's kml file. The Earth in the game is represented this way:

The map is flat with width of 43,200,000m (X goes from -21,600,000 to 21,600,000) and height of 21,600,000m (Y goes from -10,800,000 to 10,800,000)

The distance between degrees is always the same: 120,000 m in length.

How do I convert the X , Y coordinates on this map to decimal latitude/longitude in Google Earth's format?

I've tried to use these formulas:

```
 LON = (360/map width) * X   
 LAT = (180/map height) * Y
```

but the coordinates are always off by a few hundred meters. There must be something I'm missing.

Comment: "*There must be something I'm missing.*"  Indeed.  And since your post is missing it too, there is no way that we can help you.

Comment: You have already asked about this in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36792/help-converting-projection-coordinates-to-google-earth. That is better place to ask such questions, you just can clarify it. Or you can read about transformatons from projected to geographic systems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know exactly, what is your [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projections). It looks like one of cylindrical. (Hope, your datum is WGS84). 
The [Google Earth](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=148110) uses WGS84 geographic coordinates. Then you can find and use right inverse equations to go from your projected coordinates to geographic.

Maybe you can find something useful [here](http://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/coordinate%20transformations/coordtrans.html) and [here](http://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/Map%20projections/mappro.html).

Comment: Thank you for the links! I think a conformal transformation is what I need.